# Getting item from copy link

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

Is it possible to get an item from it copy link from CSOM?

[image]
So get item from this format for both folders and files.
https://xx.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/xxx/Shared%20Documents/%E2%80%99Sites-xx-xx-xx-xx.xlsx?d=w4f17cf6bd7094e988aecdf179acb3530&csf=1&web=1&e=0gneH9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m afraid not. As far as I know, there is no way to parse the share link like this:' `https://xxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/:u:/s/dev/EUDdsBKYArRDobXz-drQ4_wBh07dg8x_-XtB2Vm4A9B7Mg`',so we could not know the information about the file.